# cucumberl(Erlang) / Ubuntu error, can't execute .feature file

Tags: ubuntu, erlang

I'm having issues with cucumberl from https://github.com/membase/cucumberl which has some known issues with regards to running .feature files 
source: https://github.com/membase/cucumberl/issues/13

Does anyone here know of a potential fix for this?

Error that I got:

```
cucumberl:run("./examples/simple_sample/features/simple_sample.feature").
** exception throw: {error,nofile}
     in function  cucumberl:run_tree/2 (src/cucumberl.erl, line 41)
```

Comment: The guy that opened that issue then forked the project, try his instead: https://github.com/madtrick/cucumberl.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `{error,nofile}` means that application tried to open the file and couldn't find it. The most probable reason is that it uses some other path as root than you suppose. Try to use absolute path to the file instead of relative.